# Extracting Test Outcome( Passed , Failed Test Case/Feature Count) in BDD Jenkins

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber

Our Requirement is to Publish a custom HTML Email Message after the completion of the Cucumber(Ruby) Test 
execution. I need to Pass following in my html reports.

Test Case Passed Count , 
Test Case Fail Count , 
Pass% etc

Please let us know how I can extract those value from cucumber json report and pass it. Is there any pre define environment variable which stores those value?

Regards,
Shubhra Goyal

Comment: Have you tried JellyScript?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Jelly script?

You may want to look at these plugins that will help you.

`https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin`

`https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin`